# how can i convert an excel table to a shapefile with correct scale in arcmap?

Tags: arcmap, import, excel

i know that there is already one similar question to this one but my problem is different and none of the provided answers did resolve my problem.

i've an excel table with some rows and in each row there is the identification and the xy coordinates of an especific point. the xy coordinates were aquired with a gps and are in wgs84.

the data layer is in wgs84 too.

my problem is that every time and every way i try to import this data to a shapefile, the resulting points are perfect in form but at a ridiculous scale (1:0.89)...

exporting the table to dbf and using it gave the same result...

how can i make the data import in a way that the scale is correct?

thanks in advance =^)

-----EDIT-----

if i use the "go to xy" tool to enter the coordinates of two points manually, using the values of x and y in the excel/dbf file, the two points appear in the right places and at the right distance (which implies a correct scale)...

-----EDIT-----

excel file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3639616/xls%20to%20shp.xls

the farthest points are codigo=394 and codigo=297, with about 26.3 km between them.

Comment: Can you tell us what it is that was measured? I succeeded in importing from dbf and "add XY data", but the result doesn't look like a trail, building or anything, but like a hydra (judging from 1:372,935) - and in short other than the rather peculiar point scattering I can't see anything wrong. What do you consider "perfect in form"? And by stating the scale do you mean you can't zoom out?

Comment: this file is just a part of the total information. all together, they don't look like anything, but they represent the stops of various bus routes. the scale problem is that when i import the data, the scale that they appear in arcmap is 1:0.89 and the correct scale that shows all the points is 1:100000. you can see an image of the correct result in here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3639616/correct_shape.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my problem is that every time and
>   every way i try to import this data to
>   a shapefile

Set your map document coordinate system to WGS84 then use the 'Add XY Data' tool to add the excel spreadsheet to the map; choose the same coordinate system and the X and Y fields. 
You can add a base map from ArcGIS online for visual reference.
If this does not yield correct results you might want to take a closer look at the source data.

Comment: that was one of my experiments, but the result was the same... the source data was verified via google earth and, in some points, on the field with another gps...

Comment: Can you paste a few rows of the source file including the header (field names)?  Perhaps this has to do with the coordinate system of your document?

Comment: you can download the complete file in http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3639616/xls%20to%20shp.xls

Comment: when I follow Jakub's instructions with your file and zoom to the extent of the dots the view scale is 1:86,870. Perhaps try saving the .xls as .csv and try that instead. I used ArcMap 9.3.1. See http://imgur.com/c3NuR.png

Comment: @Marinheiro Took a look at your file in ArcMap - for me it comes out fine, so I'm afraid I'm not sure what the issue is your end. Which version of ArcGIS are you using (slim possibility, but maybe)? If it helps I've created a shapefile which you can download in a zip from http://db.tt/zltMI3k if that helps.

Comment: No issues with ArcMap 10 either. Location near the Indian Ocean, scale is fine.

Comment: @matt wilkie - with me, the result scale was always 1:0.89 in two different computers, one with arcmap 9.3 and another with 10

Comment: @om_henners - with both 9.3 and 10 the result is always the same. your shapefile has a 180º rotation. it lyes is tanzania and the real location is in portugal, in the outskirts of lisbon.

Comment: this is the correct position of all points (introduced by hand) at a scale of 1:100000 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3639616/correct_shape.jpg

Comment: I think you have your latitudes and longitudes around the wrong way I'm afraid - at least in the .xls file...

Comment: sorry, you're right... xx is yy and yy is xx... my bad... i eliminated some fields and changed a few names and that ones were wrongly changed... but, despite of that, the various methods presented here still doesn't work for me... three computers, two versions of arcmap, three windows versions, all the configurations are different... what the heck is going wrong?!?!?!?